# How do i multiply a list of values by a dataframe of values then use those results to multiply by the next row of values in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, iterator

I'm trying to code a daily stock price return simulator.  I need to take a starting allocation of funds (across say, three stocks) and multiply by a dataframe of returns for those stocks.  So for example, let's say I have an allocation of `[1000, 2000, 7000]` dollars, I multiply those values by the first row of returns, for example `[-.01, .05, .009]`.  How do I then take that result and multiply that by the next row of returns in the data frame then append each value to a dictionary?

Example code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_dict = {'ba': [.001588,.001540, .001001, .001206, .001338], 'gs':[0.001064,0.001232, 0.001748, 0.001642, 0.001616],
          'ge': [0.001030, 0.000876, 0.001335, 0.000756, .000880]}

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

allocation = [1000, 2000, 7000]
```

So I would look to multiply `1000` (first value in the allocation) by `.001588` (first value of the first column of df) and `2000`(send value in allocation) by `.001064` (first value in 2nd column of df) and the same for the third allocation/first value of the 3rd column and append the results to a dictionary with today's date as a key.

How do I take those results and multiply them by the next row's values, append them to the dictionary with today() + 1 and then do the same until I have gone through the whole data set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let pandas do the full operations by building a dataframe from the `allocation` list indexed by the expected dates:

```
ix = pd.date_range(datetime.date.today(), freq='D', periods = len(df))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [allocation], index=ix, columns = df.columns)
```

`df1` is:

```
              ba    gs    ge
2020-03-23  1000  2000  7000
2020-03-24  1000  2000  7000
2020-03-25  1000  2000  7000
2020-03-26  1000  2000  7000
2020-03-27  1000  2000  7000
```

You can use same index for the initial `df`, use a `cumprod` to multiply the rows and finally have the product of both dataframes:

```
df.set_index(ix).cumprod() * df1
```

to obtain:

```
                      ba            gs            ge
2020-03-23  1.588000e+00  2.128000e+00  7.210000e+00
2020-03-24  2.445520e-03  2.621696e-03  6.315960e-03
2020-03-25  2.447966e-06  4.582725e-06  8.431807e-06
2020-03-26  2.952246e-09  7.524834e-09  6.374446e-09
2020-03-27  3.950106e-12  1.216013e-11  5.609512e-12
```